# Как расставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Может ли кто-нибудь правильно расставить запятые в этом предложении? Буду очень признательна.

Изготовление затворов дисковых поворотных с внедрением указанных достижений позволит создать реальную конкуренцию на основании революционных существенных неоспоримых преимуществ, при сравнении с последними самыми высокими показателями затворов дисковых поворотных, производимых ведущими мировыми компаниями.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение не слишком удачное, можно предложить следующий вариант:

С внедрением указанных достижений  затворы дисковые поворотные составят реальную конкуренцию аналогичной продукции на основании  революционных, существенных, неоспоримых преимуществ их показателей по сравнению с последними самыми высокими показателями затворов, производимых ведущими мировыми компаниями.

Comment: Да, София, ваш вариант удачнее, но в вашем примере нужна запятая после "указанных достижений", также как после " последними", иначе получится, что  самые высокие показатели - последние. Тогда как здесь явное уточнение.

Answer (score 0):

Изготовление затворов дисковых поворотных с внедрением указанных достижений позволит создать реальную конкуренцию на основании революционных***,*** существенных***,*** неоспоримых преимуществ, при сравнении с последними**,** самыми высокими показателями затворов дисковых поворотных, производимых ведущими мировыми компаниями.

Comment: С "последними, самыми высокими" я соглашусь, а вот насчет первой цепочки - не уверена.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду это предложение .... " на основании революционных, существенных, неоспоримых преимуществ" ?

Comment: Да. революционных и существенных ведь не скажешь.

Answer (score 0):

Изготовление затворов дисковых поворотных, с внедрением указанных технологий, позволит создать реальную конкуренцию, на основании революционных, существенных, неоспоримых преимуществ, при сравнении с последними самыми, высокими показателями затворов дисковых поворотных, производимых  ведущими мировыми компаниями.

Comment: При сравнении с последними, самыми высокими показателями...

Comment: Да, правильно: При сравнении с последними, самыми высокими показателями... После "самыми" запятая не нужна. Как и не нужна запятая после " конкуренции".